# ClickID not firing in GTM but Clicktext variable is firing correctly. Why so?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tags, google-tag-manager, facebook-pixel

I am trying to troubleshoot something in GTM. The ClickText variable is working properly and the GTM tag (Facebook pixel in this case) is firing properly with this variable set in the trigger however the variable ClickID who is a unique identifier is not firing at all. Does anyone know why? It is really odd.

Comment: Can you please attach to your question screenshots of your triggers and sample of your HTML markup

Comment: From experince what might be happening: ClickID is ID of the actual element that is clicked, so for example if you have: <div id="example"><p>Hello</p></div> and you click on "hello" text the ClickID would be undefined because clickElement is <p> and not the top div as you would expect. ClickText will always give you text no matter how many elements you have nested there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is almost certainly the nested elements problem.
GTM ClickID recognizes the outer element that is clicked.

I've solved this in the past by using CSS-Selectors , which worked like a charm.